# Why are stoi, stol not fixed width integers?

Tags: c++, c++11

Since ints and longs and other integer types may be different sizes on different systems, why not have `stouint8_t()`, `stoint64_t()`, etc. so that portable string to int code could be written?

Comment: One wrinkle in that would be that none of the fixed width integer types are guaranteed to exist. So you'd need `sto_uint_least8_t()`, `sto_uint_fast8_t()` and so on

Comment: @Praetorian A suite of `sto<uint_least_8_t>()` etc aren't so bad.

Comment: The title of your question seems to imply you'd prefer to _only_ have functions for fixed-width integers ... is that really what you mean, or are you asking why they don't exist in addition?

Comment: I much prefer the `boost::lexical_cast` approach to this. Template the function specialized for all the basic arithmetic types, then all the fixed width type versions come with it, since they are just typedefs of the basic types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it's *usually* not necessary.

`stoll` and `stoull` return results of type `long long` and `unsigned long long` respectively. If you want to convert a string to `int64_t`, you can just call `stoll()` and store the result in your `int64_t` object; the value will be implicitly converted.

This assumes that `long long` is the widest signed integer type. Like C (starting with C99), C++ permits *extended integer types*, some of which might be wider than `[unsigned] long long`.  C provides conversion functions `strtoimax` and `strtoumax` (operating on `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t`, respectively) in `<inttypes.h>`. For whatever reason, C++ doesn't provide wrappers for this functions (the logical names would be `stoimax` and `stoumax`.

But that's not going to matter unless you're using a C++ compiler that provides an extended integer type wider than `[unsigned] long long`, and I'm not aware that any such compilers actually exist. For any types no wider than 64 bits, the existing functions are all you need.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>

int main() {
    const char *s = "0xdeadbeeffeedface";
    uint64_t u = std::stoull(s, NULL, 0);
    std::cout << u << "\n";

}
```

Comment: C++ also supports `intmax_t` but doesn't provide a `std::stoimax` wrapper around `strtoimax`

Comment: It's precisely as necessary as the fixed-size integer types themselves. Sorry but I can't agree with this assessment.

Comment: i.e. sometimes necessary and sometimes not

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Care to explain why they are so necessary? If a series of numbers is printed out _separated with some kind of delimiters_ (ex. "123,456,789"), then any `strto*()` function with a wider return type than the printing source will return the same thing. And if the values were printed out _unseparated_ (ex "123456789"), then how can anyone at all unambiguously parse this? Say, into 123, 456, 789 and not 12345, 6789, 0?

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist: It's not about ambiguous parsing. It's about _knowing_ that you're parsing into an integer type that's the correct size for some known input. I hate the implementation-defined-width types; they make no sense to me at all.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist: Huh? Given an argument like `"123456789"`, all the `sto*()` functions will parse it as a single integer, and raise an exception if the number is out of range.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Yep, concur. This answer is better now, accordingly. :P I still think it fails to address the question, though. I don't _want_ to read into an `unsigned long long`.

Answer (score 7):

Because typing that would make me want to chop off my fingers.

Seriously, the basic integer types are `int` and `long` and the `std::stoX` functions are just very simple wrappers around `strtol` etc. and note that C doesn't provide `strtoi32` or `strtoi64` or anything that `std::stouint32_t` could wrap.

If you want something more complicated you can write it yourself.

I could just as well ask "why do people use `int` and `long`, instead of `int32_t` and `int64_t` everywhere, so the code is portable?" and the answer would be because it's not always necessary.

But the actual reason is probably that noone ever proposed it for the standard. Things don't just magically appear in the standard, someone has to write a proposal and justify adding them, and convince the rest of the committee to add them. So the answer to most "why isn't this thing I just thought of in the standard?"  is that noone proposed it.

Comment: Adding `stoimax()` and `stoumax()` would be sufficient; there's no need for a conversion function for *each* of the `[u]intN_t` types.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Is it? Then you would be depending on all uses of the function getting the value into some large `intmax` type, checking that it fits within the range of the variable they want to use and using a narrowing conversion. Or maybe people would just drop a cast and do the narrowing conversion without ever considering that the value they get and the value in the string are different… yeah, I see that happening, followed by questions in SO and complains about how complicated C++ is to use right.

Comment: [to be honest that could be hidden behind a template in the library `stoi<type>(str, &endp)`… but the interface of `stoiX` is not really that great if you ask me, why extend it?]